# Server-side Value Change Events / Listeners - for all controls at once

Tags: java, xpages

I have found the following example how to monitor value changes in controls:

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=server-side-value-change-events-listeners

I would rather like to monitor multiple controls at once on my xpage.

How can I do this? I would like to have one single message box for multiple controls.